# Configparser writes to fie but returns empty result

Tags: python, ini, configparser

[image]

So this function is a cut-out, from a class that should create and then extract information from an `ini` file. The problem I have is that the `ini` file definitely shows that all the added sections exist, but whenever I want the program to extract information or read from the file, it returns `[]`, an empty list. I tried this function in a more basic version using Anaconda Navigator, well it turned out there it worked.

The screenshot shows the ini file.

As seen in the screenshot, the file is indeed not empty and the function successfully wrote to it, problem is whenever the function should print from it or when I want another function to read it, it returns [].

Code is as following:

```
class cSetup():
import os
import time
import datetime
import configparser as configparser
"""Class creates an ini file, this ini file contains a number of settings which can be read by the get function.
the program will later access this file to check for certain settings.
If the file is not existing yet, a function within the class will create it
"""
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

def write_setup(self):
    if os.path.exists("Setup.ini"):
        setup_file = open("Setup.ini", "r")
        print(self.config.read(setup_file))
        setup_file.close()
    else:
        """This function is the initial setup, it writes all the necessary information to a .ini file."""
        global config
        """Asks user for a name"""
        Name = input("Please enter your name, note this can be changed in the settings""\n"
                               "Please enter the name here: ")
        self.time.sleep(1)

        """asks user for prefered input method"""
        PreferredInput = input("Input method required: 0 Shutdown, 1 Voice Commands, 2 Text Commands, 3 Dev Mode: ")

        setup_file = open("Setup.ini", "w")
        setup_file
        self.config.write(setup_file)
        self.config.add_section("Setup state")
        self.config.set("Setup state", "Activated?", "True")  # Convert to Bool later
        section_option = "Settings"
        self.config.add_section(section_option)
        self.config.set(section_option, "Name", Name)
        self.config.set(section_option, "Preferred Input", PreferredInput)  # Convert to int later
        self.config.write(setup_file)
        setup_file = open("Setup.ini", "r")
        print(self.config.read(setup_file))
        setup_file.close()
```

Comment: What is 'self.config`?  Make a *complete* [mcve].

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: what's the screen shot supposed to show us? I've got a 34" monitor, lasik-corrected eyes, and I can barely read it

Comment: @MarkTolonen First up, sorry for making so many formal mistakes, I've never really posted anything on stackoverflow to get help.
Anyways, I've added the definition of config, hope that helped.
It's basically just assigning the ConfigParser function to the variable config to make it more easy to call it.
If there are any other questions to my code, please tell me, I really just wanna be able to continue working.
Best Regards Someone

Comment: @PaulH Hello, so the screenshot should show the .ini file, which my code is writing too. 
Just wanted to show that the file is not empty.
If it was empty, then I wouldn't have a problem, but my ini file has contents and whenever it should print anything from the file or get any information out of it, it either tells me that it's empty (which is print() returning an empty list) or it tells me that the sections, seen in the screenshot, do not exist.

Comment: @furas <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
[]
This was the output of print(file) and print(type(file))
As seen the file is recognized as empty, while it is definitely not empty if I open it in Pycharm or in my text editor